# cloudant database local cache with java api

Tags: cloudant

i am new to the cloudant , i tried searching the internet but could not found the correct reference about the Cache.

can u please provide me some reference based on java .like api,or links which reference on caching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by cache you mean replicating all or a subset of your Cloudant data to a local datastore.  If so, have a look here: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android

> Applications use Cloudant Sync to store, index and query local JSON
>   data on a device and to synchronise data between many devices.
>   Synchronisation is under the control of the application, rather than
>   being controlled by the underlying system. Conflicts are also easy to
>   manage and resolve, either on the local device or in the remote
>   database.
>
> ...
>
> This library is for Android and Java SE; an iOS version is also
>   available.

There are examples on the above page of using the library.

Where you see the word 'device' on the above page, you can also think 'java app'.